# How to merge polygons into a single item where an attribute is same?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table

I have a shapefile of an area. It consists of a list of fields in which sub-locality is also a field. Under the sub-locality field all the areas are common, say for example: perungudi, perungudi, perungudi.

When I export this shapefile in Post Gis in the sub-locality field each attribute is represented as a separate shapefile. So I want all the attributes in the sublocality field to have common boundary. How can I do this?

Comment: do you mean that you want to merge polygons into a single item where the value of sublocality is the same?

Comment: yes brother@Mark exactly the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In QGIS you could use the VECTOR > GEOPROCESSING > DISSOLVE tool and dissolve on the "sublocality" field. You will have a multipart polygon and one record for each value in the "sublocality" field.

[image: QGIS dissolve]

In ArcGIS you can use ArcToolbox > Data Management Tools > Generalisation > Dissolve and dissolve on the same field.

Comment: thank you!!!!!!brother escaped me from a great disaster!!!!!